# FosUser How can i add role field if thegrant is ADMIN

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

i want to show differante value in the roles field if the grant is admin and simple user.

Ex if the grant is role_admin i will see in the roles fields User and admin
if is role_user i will have juste User.

I use FOSuser and this is  my UserType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name')
        ->add('surname')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('mobile')
        ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => array(
                'ADMIN' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                'SIMPLE USER' => 'ROLE_USER'),
            'multiple'=>true
        ));
}/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */

public function getParent()
{
    return BaseRegistrationFormType::class;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass current user as option of your form. Then iterate over `$user->getRoles()` to generate your choices.

Like this for example:

```
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $user = $options['user'];
    $builder->add('name')
        ->add('surname')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('mobile');
    if($user instanceof User){
        $choices = [];
        foreach($user->getRoles() as $key => $role){
            /* Do your key transform process here */
            $choices[$key] = $role;
        }
        $builder->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => $choices,
            'multiple'=>true
        ));
    }
}/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */

public function getParent()
{
    return BaseRegistrationFormType::class;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
        'user'       => null
    ));
}
```

Then pass current user upon form init.